# Prove that if $\alpha$ is injective, α∗ is injective.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be groups, let $A^{'}$ and $B^{'}$ be normal subgroups of A and B and let $\alpha : A\to B$ be a homomorphism with $\alpha (A^{'}) \subseteq B^{'}$. Define $α∗ : A/A′ → B/B′$ given by $α∗ : a A′ → α(a)B′$. Prove that if $\alpha$ is injective, α∗ is injective.

I am stuck when I have to prove that $α(a_1)B′ = α(a_2)B′$ implies $a_1 = a_2$. I know that statement imply $α(a_1) = α(a_2)b′$ for some $b' \in B'$ then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: This is simply not true. Take any non trivial group $G$. Let $\alpha \colon G \to G$ be the identity map : $\alpha (g) = g,\forall g\in G$. Then, with $A' = \{e_G\}$ the trivial subgroup and $B' = G$, clearly $\alpha(A') \subseteq B'$ but $\alpha\ast$ is the unique highly non-injective map $G \to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A=B=\Bbb Z$ and $A'=4\Bbb Z $ , $B'=2\Bbb Z$ and $\alpha(x )=2x $